# Calculating the total traffic generated by an application in a network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, bandwidth

[image]

I have network (shown above) with the same application (Appx) running on the nodes (Linux nodes). This Appx has data to send the same copy of the Appx running in each node (i.e. each Appx generates data to send to every other Appx). I will like to calculate the total traffic in the network that are generated by Appx i.e. sum of all the traffic from each of the Appxs. How do I go about this? The technique I used so far is to Record the Appx traffic to and from node 1 via the interface Eth1 of node1, this serves as the traffic on link 0, record traffic to and from node 2 via Eth 2 of node 2; this serves as the Appx traffic on link 1. I do similar thing for the remaining links using to and from via Eth1 of node 4 Eth2 of node 1 and Eth1 of node 3 and Eth0 of node 2 for links 2,3,4 and 5 respectively. Then I add all this traffic in bps and this gives me the total traffic due to all instances of Appx running on the network.
**My question: is this an ideal way of doing it**?

Note that I got the traffic in each interface by running the **nload** command and Appx is the only thing running on this test network. Hence, I can safely assume that any traffic captured in this network belongs only to appx and not to say https or whatever. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is a networking question.

Comment: There are alternatives and drawbacks for each situation; one of them is the application registering the volume of traffic received; a slightly better situation would be to not have a mesh per se, but everything connected in a professional equipment capable of doing sFlow/netflow.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - This is a question about monitoring the network using Linux hosts.  Isn't that on-topic here?

Comment: not too sure what you are looking for, but perhaps it is **snmp** which can run on each node and you can interrogate from any of them and add up the results. There are command-line and graphical tools built on top of this like [cacti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacti_(software)). Do you want graphs or a total over 1 hour or an instantaneous or max value...?

Comment: yeah @meuh thanks that's an option (the snmp approach). I want to get the total over say 1 hour. But my intention is to keep the approach as simplified as possible. Is there a command to monitor traffic to and from an application ? I can always add all up later. Thanks.

Comment: `ifconfig` shows how many bytes have been transferred over each interface. You can snapshot these values and calculate the difference.

Comment: thanks @meuh I think that's as simple as it can get. I will use ifconfig. And my technique of adding up all the values I get from each node to get the total is ok right? I mean adding all the ifconfig output I get at each node as I explained in the diagram, is the right way?

Comment: to avoid any problems simply total the TX bytes on all 3 interfaces of all 4 nodes. For confidence compare this with the total RX similarly.